# Using npm mysql with angular / electron

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, ionic-framework, electron

I am trying to make desktop application using `electron`, `ionic4 --type-angular` and `npm mysql`.

I have established the connection with mysql but with normal html, js, css using the below code in my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./jquery-2.1.4.js');</script>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <h1>Electron MySQL Example</h1>
<div id="resultDiv"></div>

    <!-- All of the Node.js APIs are available in this renderer process. -->
    We are using Node.js <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
    Chromium <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
    and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.

    <script>
      // You can also require other files to run in this process
      require('./renderer.js')
    </script>

    <script>
    var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'electron_db'
});

connection.connect();

$sql = 'SELECT `emp_id`,`emp_name` FROM `employee`';
connection.query($sql, function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(results);
  $('#resultDiv').text(results[0].emp_name);
});

connection.end();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Now I have made electron app with ionic4. I have installed mysql and jquery using `npm install mysql`, `npm install jquery` in my project. I need to know how do I use the above js code in my `home.page.ts`

Below is my `home.page.ts` which is giving error
 `ERROR in src/app/home/home.page.ts(4,18): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try`npm i @types/node`.`

```
    declare var $: any;
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    var mysql      = require('mysql');
    var connection;
var $sql;
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'root',
      password : '',
      database : 'electron_db'
    });
    connection.connect();


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
    })
    export class HomePage {


    constructor(){
      $sql = 'SELECT `emp_id`,`emp_name` FROM `employee`';

      connection.query($sql, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(results);
        $('#resultDiv').text(results[0].emp_name);
      });

      connection.end();
    }
    }
```

Comment: JavaScript generally steers away from using `$` in variable names even though it is permitted, technically.

Comment: Did you verify that the type definitions are installed as the error suggests?